# Can you analyse .TAB files in QGIS? Or compare .shp to .tab?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, mapinfo, tab

I'm recently experimenting with QGIS at work (a poor charity who is struggling along with MapInfo v8).

As all our layers are in .TAB format and I was wondering if you can use the geoprocessing tools to analyse this data in QGIS or if you have to convert to .SHP first?

Also, if I was being difficult, could I use the intersect tool to see how much of a .SHP polygon was inside a .TAB polygon?

I didn't work when I tried, but this may be due to me missing something else.

Comment: In which way it did not work?

Comment: it works fine for me, which Qgis are you using?

Comment: It was v2.14. Looking into it a bit further, I think it may have been because the projections were different. I had OTF on. (p.s. sorry for the delayed reply - I went on my hols and forgot about GIS for a while!).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should be able to use the majority of geoprocessing tools on .tab files. I just tested running the **Intersection** tool with the .tab file as *input layer* and the polygon shapefile as the *intersect layer*:

[image: Result]

You can then use the **Field Calculator** on the output layer and use an expression like `$area` to calculate how much of the .shp file was inside the .tab file.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply. I still couldn't get the thing to work but I think that may be due to differing projections rather than the different formats.

Comment: @MatG - Most welcome! Yes, you always have to make sure that when you're geospatially analysing one layer with another, they all must be in the same CRS ;)